# VB.NET Use Regex to split string on single commas, but not on double commas

Tags: regex, vb.net

There's a file I'm trying to use for a list of strings that has the following rules:

1. Cannot begin or end with an unescaped comma.
2. A comma is escaped by a preceding comma.
3. Strings are separated by unescaped commas.
4. Everything else is absolutely face-value.

I've been fiddling around with some VB.NET code to parse a file like this and split it up into either a `String()` or a `List(Of String)`, but it's gotten to be a little annoying.  It's not that I can't figure this out; it's that I don't want to write crap code.  If it's unnecessarily confusing, unecessarily slow, or anything else like that, it's not good enough.

Now, I know this almost starts to sound a little like a Code Review question, but I'm really starting to think that maybe a good regex would work better than trying to do this programmatically.  Unfortunately regexes are not easy to work with, and while using one to tell it to escape on a comma may be a trivial matter, getting it to also ignore double commas and such is a bit more of an issue, at least for somebody who's not used to regexes.

How do you do this (properly) in VB.NET?  In particular, I'm having a little bit of trouble putting together a wild card that'll match anything at all but a comma.  It's also taking me a little bit to find out whether #1 has to be verified programmatically, or whether it can be done in the regex itself at the same time as the split operation.

**EDIT**

I just "woke up" and realized that this syntax is ambiguous, since in an odd-numbered series of three or more commas, you don't know what's escaped and what isn't.  I'm just going to accept the current answer and move on.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've got a regex reference in front of me; I'm still looking through it and trying to put something together to try.  In particular, It's taking me a little while to find something that says "any character at all but this particular one".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used VB.net in a long time ... but I would't got the RegEx way.

What about splitting the string by "," ...

```
Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

You will get a list of items, now you only need to take care of the empty items (escaped commas) and join them with the correct preceding item.

PS: not sure if split gives you empty items in case of ",,"

Comment: Is using this and the concatenation a lot more efficient than regex?

Comment: The code will be simpler to understand than a RegEx, not even sure if this can be done via RegEx. And probably faster, but without testing hard to tell.